# Ruby - class variables being overwritten on successive reads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class like so:

```
class MyNumber
  @@number = nil

  unless @@number
    @@number = rand(10)
  end

  def number
    @@number
  end
end
```

When I subsequently call the number method on this class the number keeps changing. I just want to set this number once and have it remain the same for the entire life of the class. How can I achieve this.

In java parlance, I am trying to have a static variable and static method for this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was being caused by rails auto unloading/reloading. There is a workaround that lets the class persist across requests.

In my environment.rb I had to add this

```
config.after_initialize do
  require 'my_number'
end
```

Comment: Another option is to add the my_number.rb file to the config/initializers directory. This achieves the same thing as doing a require in environment.rb

Answer (score 1):

It should work, but how are you calling the class - if the class is reloaded it will have a different value.

Comment: I am using it in an ERB template in rails. I have no idea why it would be reloading the class for every request even though nothing has changed.

The real issue is that I am accessing some Java libraries through JRuby and they don't like to be instantiated more than once.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be better written like this:

```
class MyNumber
  def number
    @@number ||= rand(10)
  end
end
```